# How can I tell if the Pause/Break key is working?

Tags: shortcut-keys

How can I tell if the <kbd>Pause</kbd> key is working in Ubuntu?

The tilde (<kbd>~</kbd>) key is not working without holding the <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> key. Maybe something similar works for the <kbd>Pause</kbd> key.

It seems to work in <kbd>System Settings</kbd>→<kbd>Keyboard</kbd>→<kbd>Shortcuts</kbd>, but when I'm playing a game which needs this specific key, it does nothing.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: The tild (~) key is also working in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts without holding right-alt key.

Comment: @snoop: You know [the drill](http://askubuntu.com/posts/229004/revisions) by now...  **;-)**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can test that any key is working with the `xev` command.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal window, then type `xev`. Another popup window opens but you can ignore that (it displays mouse activity). Watch the terminal output while pressing the <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> key and see if there is any output. Here's mine:

[image: xev output in terminal]

Note that the window created by `xev` will need to be the window in focus, otherwise, the utility won't capture the key press.

For how to use this data, or to remap the key, see [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2392/re-mapping-keyboard-keys).

Comment: @Flimm thanks for the edit. I didn't know about the focus.

Answer (score 18):

I've written an in-browser test, so you can test this without having to open the terminal.

Simply press the <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> key and see if it's working.

⇒ [Pause/Break key test](http://fiddle.jshell.net/kGA78/show/)

Comment: A fiddle is not a reliable answer, there should be the js source here.