# 13.04 - Fn volume keys not working on Dell Inspiron 1470

Tags: 12.10, inspiron, function-keys

I'm using a Dell Inspiron 1470, and eversince I updated to 13.04, none of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys are working, except for brightness and WiFi.

Comment: Does your sound icon in the bar show? And can you adjust sound settings manually?

Comment: yes the icon shows and i can change it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Ubuntu is simply seeing them as regular keys. If so then you could remap them.

See if this helps: [Re-mapping keyboard keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2392/re-mapping-keyboard-keys)

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded keytouch editor, but i cant seem to make it work. I'd be grateful if you could help me a little more!

After i opened it, I selected "ATI translated set 2 keyboard", and started adding the keys, which were recognized right away as "mute", "volume up", etc.. yet i dont know how to save it or  actually set it on, because it doesnt work anyway. 

"Mute" "Volume Up" and "Volume down" show on the side panel "plugin: Amixer" and their respective functions.

"Previous" "play/pause" and "next" show "plugin: xmms" and their functions.

Comment: funny thing yet, i downloaded Amarok and "Previous" "Play/pause" and "Next" keys worked fine, but only with that one application.

Comment: Did you see this page? It might help. See if you can install the closest one matching your laptop - http://keytouch.sourceforge.net/keyboards_dell.php

Comment: yeah i saw it, but when i try to import the files, it says the format's not the right one. I even tried to make my own config using keytouch editor, but when i try to import it I get the same message...
I also realised that fn keys do work when i use xbmc too.

Comment: What does `xev` show you?

Comment: it's too long to post it here for each key but as in an example:
For the mute key:

"KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5c00001,
    root 0x84, subw 0x0, time 589296, (-206,498), root:(462,550),
    state 0x0, keycode 121 (keysym 0x1008ff12, XF86AudioMute), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False"

And so on with Audio lower volume, audio raise volume, audioprev, audioplay, audionext, and eject.

Comment: If the `Fn` + each key works, then that means you can map the keys in a custom way. If you can find an app that can map any key to volume, etc., then you could simply do it that way. (I hope I'm not telling you something you already know)

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I have  the same issue on Dell Inspirion 15r SE with Ubuntu 14.04. After a reboot the function keys works well.